# Using dotenv for API keys in multiple JS files

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, dotenv

I am new to web programming but not programming in general. I use node.js to create a website and am using dotenv to hide API info form github and am having some trouble understanding something.

My .env file is in the root directory and contains:

```
GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_KEY=key_value
```

I use an app.js file to set up and run my server and send the index.html file.

```
//jshint esversion:6
const https = require('https');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.listen(5000, function(req, res) {
    console.log("Listening on port 5000.");
});
```

Then I have another script file I use named "custom.js" to run the bulk of my webapp. Inside, I try to use process.env to get the API key.

```
window.onload = function()
{
  const googleAPIkey = process.env.GOOGLE_CALEDAR_API_KEY;
.
.
.
```

but I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined"

I have also tried moving the require("dotenv").config() line to the custom.js file and that fails. There is something I am doing wrong with trying to access information from one file into another, but I don't understand what.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share a link to your github repo? It looks like you have everything setup correctly based on your Post

Comment: My github is https://github.com/Sir-Mann/BluestoneBaptistWeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what's i understood you trying to access the process variable of node.js app from the client browser and it is not possible. The process variable is only accessible in the scope of the node.js application and not in the browser where you run your client.

Comment: So, are you saying that I need to use the api from within my app.js file where the server is running, instead of the custom.js file which runs on the client?

Comment: Yes, you can only access the process variable inside the node.js application scope

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `require("dotenv").config();` on second script file also

Comment: I tried that, but there is an error saying "require" is undefined.

Comment: I think you are using this on client side javascript. And NodeJs api does not work on client side

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access the Process variable on the client-side / frontend. You cannot access those variables from a client browser or machine